# Is it possible to set the root path of an dynamically created iframe in JavaScript or html?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

Here what i'm trying to do :

```
var html = '<html><head><script src="/js/script.js"></script></head><body></body></html>';
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDocument.open();
iframeDocument.write(html);
iframeDocument.close();
```

I want to set the relative path of my iframe. My script is at http://qwerty.com/iframe/js/script but my top page is at http://qwerty.com/ so the script do not load. Is it possible to set the root path of an dynamically created iframe in JavaScript or html?

Comment: Why can't you just update your `html` variable to have the correct path?

Comment: `html.replace(/\/js\/script.js/,'/iframe/js/script.js')`?

Comment: No and yes... No because this is a preview of the page I will create and yes because I was thinking about setting the full url of the script, but in my context it would be better to have a relative path. I really don't think setting the root path is possible, so I probably have to deal with absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
var relativeTo = 'http://qwerty/iframe/';
html = html.replace(/src="((/?[a-z0-9-]+/?)*([a-z0-9]).js)"/g,'src="'+relativeTo+'/$1"');
```